# How do I get the Android R.file to update automatically quicker?

Tags: android, file, r.java-file

Sometimes the R.file updates immediately for me, other times it takes a long time to update when I add @+id in my xml files, is there a way to speed this automatic process up especially for times when it takes 15-20min

Comment: after edit the xml file, rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need more details.

I'm assuming you are referring to your IDE not refreshing quickly enough.

What IDE are you using? If you are using eclipse for instance, you can select Project->Clean and do a clean build of your project. That will generate the R file again.

Comment: Also, sometimes if you just cannot get the project to generate an R file, it could be because there is a mismatch between the Android version declared in the manifest and the one selected as the project build target in Eclipse. This is normally only the case if you've imported or copied an existing project into your workspace.